# Smaller Size Youtube Video not working inside Swiper

Tags: jquery, youtube, youtube-api, swiper.js

i am currently working in a website in which the player size of **Youtube Video** is less than 150x150 which is inside a [iDangero.us Swiper](http://www.idangero.us/sliders/swiper/index.php) which is jquery swiper plugin...

I have tried with applying custom size as follows:-

[image: Youtube player]

But its creating problem with the player in Firefox it shows black box and shows a error is the console:-

**My demo:-**

[image: My demo]

**Error:-**

```
NS_ERROR_XPC_BAD_CONVERT_JS: Could not convert JavaScript argument arg 1 [nsIDOMEventTarget.removeEventListener]
```

I have tested also on Chrome it show fine in that...

I am using this code:-

```
<div class="swiper-container swiper-vid">
                            <div class="swiper-wrapper">
                              <div class="swiper-slide">
                                <div class="vid-contain">
                                <div class="videoWrapper">
                                    <!-- Copy & Pasted from YouTube -->
                                    <iframe width="142" height="80" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/_wmzPRwLIaM?showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                                </div>
                                <p>Slide 1</p>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                              <div class="swiper-slide">
                                <div class="vid-contain">
                                <div class="videoWrapper">
                                    <!-- Copy & Pasted from YouTube -->
                                    <iframe width="142" height="80" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/Mn63rXCkCxY?showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                                </div>
                                <p>Slide 2</p>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                              <div class="swiper-slide">
                                <div class="vid-contain">
                                <div class="videoWrapper">
                                    <!-- Copy & Pasted from YouTube -->
                                    <iframe width="142" height="80" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/_wmzPRwLIaM?showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                                </div>
                                <p>Slide 3</p>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                              <div class="swiper-slide">
                                <div class="vid-contain">
                                <div class="videoWrapper">
                                    <!-- Copy & Pasted from YouTube -->
                                    <iframe width="142" height="80" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/Mn63rXCkCxY?showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                                </div>
                                <p>Slide 4</p>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                              <div class="swiper-slide">
                                <div class="vid-contain">
                                <div class="videoWrapper">
                                    <!-- Copy & Pasted from YouTube -->
                                    <iframe width="142" height="80" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/_wmzPRwLIaM?showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                                </div>
                                <p>Slide 5</p>
                                </div>
                              </div> 
                              <div class="swiper-slide">
                                <div class="vid-contain">
                                <div class="videoWrapper">
                                    <!-- Copy & Pasted from YouTube -->
                                    <iframe width="142" height="80" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/Mn63rXCkCxY?showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                                </div>
                                <p>Slide 6</p>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                              <div class="swiper-slide">
                                <div class="vid-contain">
                                <div class="videoWrapper">
                                    <!-- Copy & Pasted from YouTube -->
                                    <iframe width="142" height="80" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/_wmzPRwLIaM?showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                                </div>
                                <p>Slide 7</p>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                              <div class="swiper-slide">
                                <div class="vid-contain">
                                <div class="videoWrapper">
                                    <!-- Copy & Pasted from YouTube -->
                                    <iframe width="142" height="80" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/Mn63rXCkCxY?showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                                </div>
                                <p>Slide 8</p> 
                                </div>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
```

**Js used:-**

```
swiperVid = $('.swiper-vid').swiper({
        slidesPerSlide : 3,
        calculateHeight:true
    });
```

What will the the solution for this? Have i mistaken somewhere...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

idangerous Swiper using CSS3 transform prevents the controls of the youtube video from being displayed and also prevent the full-screen option of it.

Setting the `backface-visibility` property on `.swiper-container` will prevent the full-screen
 transform3d CSS on `.swiper-wrapper` class prevent the controls of the youtube and make many other issues like the black screen, Audio playing without video etc...

so I think you should put in your consideration to change the idangerous Swiper if you want the youtube video to play properly.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

1. ADD `?html5=1` to your embed link
2. Add `useCSS3Transforms: false` to the swiper attributes.

Works like a charm :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried typing the full url instead of just the /file name in the src attribute? Give it a try and let me know if that helps.

**Update:**

Try to change the `useCSS3Transforms` option to `false` on the function that builds the swiper, I had this issue too and fixed with that. Somehow it causes the YouTube iframe to break on iOS too.

Answer (score 0):

Disabling css3 transitions was not enough for me. I had an html5 video delivered through ooyla inside swiper slides.

I had to turn off css3transitions AND disable looping for my video to load correctly.

```
$('.swiper-container').swiper({
    mode:'horizontal',
    useCSS3Transforms: false,
    loop: false
});
```

My videos now play!